# Shortest distance with complex number in network x

Tags: graph, networkx

I have a graph, where the edge weights are complex numbers. I am trying to get the weighted shortest path length but I got an error.
Does `networkx` support complex weights?

Here is a sample code:

```py
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_nodes_from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

G.add_edge(1, 2, weight=complex(1, 2))
G.add_edge(1, 3, weight=complex(3, 4))
G.add_edge(2, 4, weight=complex(5, 6))
G.add_edge(3, 4, weight=complex(7, 8))
G.add_edge(4, 5, weight=complex(9, 10))

shortest_path = nx.shortest_path_length(G, 1, 5, weight='weight')
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'complex' and 'complex'

Comment: Your question is more mathematical in nature: When is `(a + bi) < (c + di)` true? Is `3i < 2`? What about `(1 + 9999i) < 2`? You need some form of distance metric to definitively order these numbers. For example in euclidian space: for `a + bi`: the distance `d = sqrt(a^2 + b^2)` represents their un-normed vector.

Comment: I was asking if networkx can support complex numbers and to get the abs of the complex number in the code).

Comment: Still, @Rogue's comment stands: NetworkX cannot compute shortest paths, because comparisons cannot be made between complex numbers. That is exactly what the error states: '<' is not supported between complex numbers, exactly because you cannot really define such measure between complex numbers, what is bigger: `1+2i` or `2+i`?


If I understand well, you just need the absolute value of complex numbers. You could either create a copy graph where you redefine the weights to be the absolute value, or when calling the shortest path function, use a function as the weight argument (documentation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would take the absolute value of the complex numbers as edge weights, you can [input a function for the weight argument](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.generic.shortest_path.html) to compute the shortest path this way:

```py
def abs_weight(v, w, edge_data):
    return abs(edge_data['weight'])

shortest_path = nx.shortest_path(G, 1, 5, weight=abs_weight)
```

From here, you can compute the "complex path length" of the path like this:

```py
def complex_path_length(G, source, target, path):
    edges = zip(path, path[1:]) #First element source node, second element target
    return sum(G.edges[u, v]['weight'] for u, v in edges)

complex_path_length(G, 1, 5, shortest_path)
```

If the assumption is wrong (e.g., you only want to take the real part of the complex numbers while computing the shortest path), you can define a similar metric to convert the weights into real numbers.
If you do not need the complex path length, just the absolute value one (or something real valued), you can use the `shortest_path_length` function in one row.

Comment: That is a good solution for calculating the shortest path, but I want to calculate the shortest path length. Is there a way to get the length of a path? so the first step is to get the shortest path (as you proposed) and then calculate the path length with the complex numbers? this way there are no need for comparing complex numbers

Comment: @TSobhy I added that part to my comment, please check it.